# Which is the best method to redirect after login in FOSUserBundle

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

Which is the best method to implement role based redirect after login in FOSUserBundle ?

Should I use a success handler and write the redirection logic in onAuthenticationSuccess

or Should I use a security listener and write the redirection logic in onSecurityInteractiveLogin

Comment: See [this post by Dustin Dobervich](http://www.dobervich.com/2011/10/13/login-redirection-revisited/). Works well!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think security listeners are used by other bundles to do some post-login operations like table update, setting cookie etc. While same can be done by success_handler, it is called once for each firewall configuration in app/config/security.yml. So you have full control over it. So I think it is better to implement redirection logic in onAuthenticationSuccess method of your success_handler service class.